# How do I pass a variable to a python script run from crontab?

Tags: python, cron

I am running a python script using the following command:

```
0,30 * * * * python /home/pi/pythonscripts/script.py &
```

and I would like to pass a variable 'test' to the script in the crontab, something like so:

```
0,30 * * * * python /home/pi/pythonscripts/script.py & test='hello'
```

Does anybody in the raspberry pi community have any idea how to do this?

Comment: For starters: I believe that the ampersand goes to the end of the command (after parameters) and is also not necessary for scripts run via cron. That being said, commands run by cron should accept parameters as given in the crontab.

Comment: The ampersand is terminating the command line, so adding test='hello' is really adding a completely new command that would be executed immediately, not waiting for the script.py to finish first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ampersand (for sending a process in the background) is not necessary for commands issued to cron via the crontab as processes are already forked. The given examples work fine without the `&`. Actually the first version shows working parameters as it invokes the python interpreter with the filename of the script to be executed as parameter.

```
0,30 * * * * python /home/pi/pythonscripts/script.py foobar
```

or

```
0,30 * * * * /home/pi/pythonscripts/script.py foobar
```

where `script.py` contains the first line `#!/bin/python3` and has executable flags.

An example how to use and print the passed parameter (per question of the OP):

```
import sys 
for arg in sys.argv:
    print(arg)
```

Parsing through the list `argv` that contains the parameters passed to the script. `argv[0]` contains the name (and path) of the script. `argv[1]` is the first parameter, and so on. For more serious handling of arguments it is advisable to use [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) ([tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html)) instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: How would I print the text foobar in Python?

Comment: For one thing: `import sys` and then use the `sys.argv` list, e.g. `argv[0]` is the name of the script, `argv[1]` is the first parameter, and so on. Easily parse through the list with something like: `for arg in sys.argv:`

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to remove the `&` sign as mentioned above. Cron forks processes already.

There are several ways to pass parameter to your script. Here are some examples (but not limited to):

1. Using [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) list. Pass it as an argument `script.py parameter1`
2. Using [Python getopt module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getopt.html) to parse parameters. Similar to above, but with more possibilities to do things like `script.py --param1=yes --param2=data`
3. Using [os.environ](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) dictionary. Pass it using environment variables `PARAM1=yes script.py`

Methods #1 and #2 are usually preferred.

Comment: Hello super old post... Can a cron service be used with argparse for optional parameters?

Comment: @HenryHub, I see no issues why not. But if you have a question, you better ask as a new question instead of commenting on the unrelated one. This way you get more visibility and answers.